# Counting word occurence in textfile

Tags: c++

Here's the code that I based here http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2015/02/c-program-count-occurrence-word-text-file.html. (new in c++)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
  // std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
 // return 0;

 ifstream fin("my_data.txt"); //opening text file
 int count=0;
 char ch[20],c[20];

 cout<<"Enter a word to count:";
 gets(c);

 while(fin)
 {
  fin>>ch;
  if(strcmp(ch,c)==0)
   count++;
 } 

 cout<<"Occurrence="<<count<<"n";
 fin.close(); //closing file

 return 0;

}
```

**Error in Patter Counting**

my_data.txt has only 3 "world" in it, but as I run the program, it results to

[image]

here's the textfile's content

[image]
What could go wrong?

Comment: Can you share the contents of my_data.txt? (or at least a portion of it, if it's too large)

Comment: sure, will update the question

Comment: So when you stepped through it in your debugger, what did it say that ch had been populated with?  Was it what you expected?

Comment: Since you use c++, would you consider using std::string as well?

Comment: Read about how to structure an input loop [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using std::string

```
int count = 0;
std::string word_to_find, word_inside_file;

std::ifstream fin("my_data.txt");
std::cout << "Enter a word to count:";
std::cin >> word_to_find;
while (fin >> word_inside_file) {
    if (word_to_find == word_inside_file )
        count++;
}

std::cout << "Occurrence=" << count << "";
```

If you want to find all occurrences inside other strings as well, as mentioned in the comments, you can do something like this:

```
...
while (fin >> word_inside_file) {
    count += findAllOccurrences(word_to_find, word_inside_file);
}
...
```

Inside `findAllOccurrences(std::string, std::string)` you will implement a "find all string occurrences inside another string" algorithm.

Comment: Hi, this works well, but when i create NO Space in between the words, it no longer read correctly like "worldworldworld"

Comment: because fin >> word_inside_file will read one whole string at a time, which in this case will be worldworldworld which is different string from world.

Comment: right. that's why I use char in my previous sample, is there a way to do it when there's no space?

Comment: You can use std::string::find and std::string::substr but you will have to implement some algorithm there because find only returns the first occurrence. This is a question, find all string occurrences in another string.

Comment: as per this question, i am accepting this answer. thanks

Comment: Words fundamentally have spaces between them, otherwise words like otherwise might be two words, other and wise, rather than otherwise. If you want to start finding substrings that's a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to c++ you shouldn't really use gets. Read about "buffer overflow vulnerability". gets() is more like c-style. You should consider using std::cin.

Comment: `gets` has been removed from C six years ago.

Comment: reference please?

Comment: [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets). Note the "until C11" tag. `gets` has been deprecated forever, and finally removed in C11.